# Hi i am working on a query which contains a group by clause. i will attach the table with data below. with previous and after scenarios

Tags: mysql, sql, database, group-by

| stopid | routeid | delid | arrivaldate | departuredate | stopNo | noofitems |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 112 | 22 | 1234 | 2022-10-04 | 2022-10-05 | 1.01 | 1000 |
| 232 | 22 | 2341 | 2022-10-05 | 2022-10-06 | 1.00 | 2000 |

i want a query to group by these 2 records in to one record like below

| routeid | arrivaldate | departuredate | noofitems | stopNo |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 22 | 2022-10-04 | 2022-10-06 | 3000 | 1.00 |

Answer (score 0):

You may aggregate by route and then take aggregates to obtain the desired column output:

```sql
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY routeid ORDER BY departuredate DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    routeid,
    MIN(arrivaldate) AS arrivaldate,
    MAX(departuredate) AS departuredate,
    SUM(noofitems) AS noofitems,
    MAX(CASE WHEN rn = 1 THEN stopNo END) AS stopNo
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    routeid;
```

### Demo